# FileReaderSync shows data but alert shows empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, filereader

I tried all possible ways by using callback, $.when, deferred (but I need to run multiple times at time) in client side. Data appears in text boxes but showing into alert is empty.

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var files = e.data;
  var buffers = [];

  // Read each file synchronously as an ArrayBuffer and
  // stash it in a global array to return to the main app.
  [].forEach.call(files, function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReaderSync();
    buffers.push({
      data: reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file),
      name: file.name
    });
  });

  postMessage(buffers);
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="filename" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<script>
  var worker = new Worker('js/worker.js');

  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('text1').value = e.data;
    //console.log(e.data); // e.data should be an array of ArrayBuffers.
  };

  worker.onerror = function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#error').textContent = [
      'ERROR: Line ', e.lineno, ' in ', e.filename, ': ', e.message
    ].join('');
  };
  alert('Load');
  document.getElementById('filename').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    worker.postMessage(this.files);
    alert('Data Load' + document.getElementById('text1').value);
  }, false);
</script>

<input type="text" id="text1" value="text" />
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: `alert()` appear to be called before `document.getElementById('text1').value = e.data;` set at  `worker.onmessage` ? Though `"text"` should be alerted at initial file upload to worker